# How can i fetch values from database using node-postgres

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, discord.js, node-postgres

I’m having a hard time fetching column values from a database table.
Here is the output instead of the values:

[image: output while running the code]

I’ve tried console logging the variables and they output correctly. Here is the console.log result:

```
2021-04-09T07:12:36.896383+00:00 app[worker.1]: Result {
2021-04-09T07:12:36.896396+00:00 app[worker.1]:   command: 'SELECT',
2021-04-09T07:12:36.896396+00:00 app[worker.1]:   rowCount: 1,
2021-04-09T07:12:36.896396+00:00 app[worker.1]:   oid: null,
2021-04-09T07:12:36.896398+00:00 app[worker.1]:   rows: [ { name: 'carryminati' } ],
2021-04-09T07:12:36.896399+00:00 app[worker.1]:   fields: [
2021-04-09T07:12:36.896399+00:00 app[worker.1]:     Field {
2021-04-09T07:12:36.896400+00:00 app[worker.1]:       name: 'name',
2021-04-09T07:12:36.896400+00:00 app[worker.1]:       tableID: 16732955,
2021-04-09T07:12:36.896400+00:00 app[worker.1]:       columnID: 3,
2021-04-09T07:12:36.896401+00:00 app[worker.1]:       dataTypeID: 1043,
2021-04-09T07:12:36.896401+00:00 app[worker.1]:       dataTypeSize: -1,
2021-04-09T07:12:36.896401+00:00 app[worker.1]:       dataTypeModifier: 22,
2021-04-09T07:12:36.896402+00:00 app[worker.1]:       format: 'text'
2021-04-09T07:12:36.896402+00:00 app[worker.1]:     }
2021-04-09T07:12:36.896403+00:00 app[worker.1]:   ],
2021-04-09T07:12:36.896403+00:00 app[worker.1]:   _parsers: [ [Function: noParse] ],
2021-04-09T07:12:36.896403+00:00 app[worker.1]:   _types: TypeOverrides {
2021-04-09T07:12:36.896404+00:00 app[worker.1]:     _types: {
2021-04-09T07:12:36.896404+00:00 app[worker.1]:       getTypeParser: [Function: getTypeParser],
2021-04-09T07:12:36.896404+00:00 app[worker.1]:       setTypeParser: [Function: setTypeParser],
2021-04-09T07:12:36.896405+00:00 app[worker.1]:       arrayParser: [Object],
2021-04-09T07:12:36.896405+00:00 app[worker.1]:       builtins: [Object]
2021-04-09T07:12:36.896406+00:00 app[worker.1]:     },
2021-04-09T07:12:36.896406+00:00 app[worker.1]:     text: {},
2021-04-09T07:12:36.896406+00:00 app[worker.1]:     binary: {}
2021-04-09T07:12:36.896407+00:00 app[worker.1]:   },
2021-04-09T07:12:36.896407+00:00 app[worker.1]:   RowCtor: null,
2021-04-09T07:12:36.896408+00:00 app[worker.1]:   rowAsArray: false
2021-04-09T07:12:36.896408+00:00 app[worker.1]: } Result {
2021-04-09T07:12:36.896408+00:00 app[worker.1]:   command: 'SELECT',
2021-04-09T07:12:36.896409+00:00 app[worker.1]:   rowCount: 1,
2021-04-09T07:12:36.896409+00:00 app[worker.1]:   oid: null,
2021-04-09T07:12:36.896409+00:00 app[worker.1]:   rows: [ { botsay: 'Hey @everyone' } ],
2021-04-09T07:12:36.896410+00:00 app[worker.1]:   fields: [
2021-04-09T07:12:36.896410+00:00 app[worker.1]:     Field {
2021-04-09T07:12:36.896410+00:00 app[worker.1]:       name: 'botsay',
2021-04-09T07:12:36.896411+00:00 app[worker.1]:       tableID: 16732955,
2021-04-09T07:12:36.896411+00:00 app[worker.1]:       columnID: 2,
2021-04-09T07:12:36.896412+00:00 app[worker.1]:       dataTypeID: 1043,
2021-04-09T07:12:36.896412+00:00 app[worker.1]:       dataTypeSize: -1,
2021-04-09T07:12:36.896412+00:00 app[worker.1]:       dataTypeModifier: 24,
2021-04-09T07:12:36.896413+00:00 app[worker.1]:       format: 'text'
2021-04-09T07:12:36.896413+00:00 app[worker.1]:     }
2021-04-09T07:12:36.896413+00:00 app[worker.1]:   ],
2021-04-09T07:12:36.896414+00:00 app[worker.1]:   _parsers: [ [Function: noParse] ],
2021-04-09T07:12:36.896414+00:00 app[worker.1]:   _types: TypeOverrides {
2021-04-09T07:12:36.896415+00:00 app[worker.1]:     _types: {
2021-04-09T07:12:36.896415+00:00 app[worker.1]:       getTypeParser: [Function: getTypeParser],
2021-04-09T07:12:36.896415+00:00 app[worker.1]:       setTypeParser: [Function: setTypeParser],
2021-04-09T07:12:36.896416+00:00 app[worker.1]:       arrayParser: [Object],
2021-04-09T07:12:36.896416+00:00 app[worker.1]:       builtins: [Object]
2021-04-09T07:12:36.896416+00:00 app[worker.1]:     },
2021-04-09T07:12:36.896417+00:00 app[worker.1]:     text: {},
2021-04-09T07:12:36.896417+00:00 app[worker.1]:     binary: {}
2021-04-09T07:12:36.896417+00:00 app[worker.1]:   },
2021-04-09T07:12:36.896418+00:00 app[worker.1]:   RowCtor: null,
2021-04-09T07:12:36.896418+00:00 app[worker.1]:   rowAsArray: false
2021-04-09T07:12:36.896418+00:00 app[worker.1]: } Result {
2021-04-09T07:12:36.896419+00:00 app[worker.1]:   command: 'SELECT',
2021-04-09T07:12:36.896419+00:00 app[worker.1]:   rowCount: 1,
2021-04-09T07:12:36.896419+00:00 app[worker.1]:   oid: null,
2021-04-09T07:12:36.896421+00:00 app[worker.1]:   rows: [ { channelid: '770245428876148736' } ],
2021-04-09T07:12:36.896421+00:00 app[worker.1]:   fields: [
2021-04-09T07:12:36.896421+00:00 app[worker.1]:     Field {
2021-04-09T07:12:36.896422+00:00 app[worker.1]:       name: 'channelid',
2021-04-09T07:12:36.896423+00:00 app[worker.1]:       tableID: 16732955,
2021-04-09T07:12:36.896423+00:00 app[worker.1]:       columnID: 4,
2021-04-09T07:12:36.896424+00:00 app[worker.1]:       dataTypeID: 1043,
2021-04-09T07:12:36.896424+00:00 app[worker.1]:       dataTypeSize: -1,
2021-04-09T07:12:36.896424+00:00 app[worker.1]:       dataTypeModifier: 41,
2021-04-09T07:12:36.896425+00:00 app[worker.1]:       format: 'text'
2021-04-09T07:12:36.896425+00:00 app[worker.1]:     }
2021-04-09T07:12:36.896426+00:00 app[worker.1]:   ],
2021-04-09T07:12:36.896426+00:00 app[worker.1]:   _parsers: [ [Function: noParse] ],
2021-04-09T07:12:36.896426+00:00 app[worker.1]:   _types: TypeOverrides {
2021-04-09T07:12:36.896427+00:00 app[worker.1]:     _types: {
2021-04-09T07:12:36.896427+00:00 app[worker.1]:       getTypeParser: [Function: getTypeParser],
2021-04-09T07:12:36.896427+00:00 app[worker.1]:       setTypeParser: [Function: setTypeParser],
2021-04-09T07:12:36.896428+00:00 app[worker.1]:       arrayParser: [Object],
2021-04-09T07:12:36.896428+00:00 app[worker.1]:       builtins: [Object]
2021-04-09T07:12:36.896428+00:00 app[worker.1]:     },
2021-04-09T07:12:36.896429+00:00 app[worker.1]:     text: {},
2021-04-09T07:12:36.896429+00:00 app[worker.1]:     binary: {}
2021-04-09T07:12:36.896429+00:00 app[worker.1]:   },
2021-04-09T07:12:36.896430+00:00 app[worker.1]:   RowCtor: null,
2021-04-09T07:12:36.896430+00:00 app[worker.1]:   rowAsArray: false
2021-04-09T07:12:36.896431+00:00 app[worker.1]: } Result {
2021-04-09T07:12:36.896431+00:00 app[worker.1]:   command: 'SELECT',
2021-04-09T07:12:36.896432+00:00 app[worker.1]:   rowCount: 1,
2021-04-09T07:12:36.896432+00:00 app[worker.1]:   oid: null,
2021-04-09T07:12:36.896432+00:00 app[worker.1]:   rows: [ { channel: 'manager-test' } ],
2021-04-09T07:12:36.896433+00:00 app[worker.1]:   fields: [
2021-04-09T07:12:36.896433+00:00 app[worker.1]:     Field {
2021-04-09T07:12:36.896434+00:00 app[worker.1]:       name: 'channel',
2021-04-09T07:12:36.896434+00:00 app[worker.1]:       tableID: 16732955,
2021-04-09T07:12:36.896434+00:00 app[worker.1]:       columnID: 5,
2021-04-09T07:12:36.896435+00:00 app[worker.1]:       dataTypeID: 1043,
2021-04-09T07:12:36.896435+00:00 app[worker.1]:       dataTypeSize: -1,
2021-04-09T07:12:36.896435+00:00 app[worker.1]:       dataTypeModifier: 34,
2021-04-09T07:12:36.896436+00:00 app[worker.1]:       format: 'text'
2021-04-09T07:12:36.896436+00:00 app[worker.1]:     }
2021-04-09T07:12:36.896436+00:00 app[worker.1]:   ],
2021-04-09T07:12:36.896437+00:00 app[worker.1]:   _parsers: [ [Function: noParse] ],
2021-04-09T07:12:36.896437+00:00 app[worker.1]:   _types: TypeOverrides {
2021-04-09T07:12:36.896438+00:00 app[worker.1]:     _types: {
2021-04-09T07:12:36.896438+00:00 app[worker.1]:       getTypeParser: [Function: getTypeParser],
2021-04-09T07:12:36.896438+00:00 app[worker.1]:       setTypeParser: [Function: setTypeParser],
2021-04-09T07:12:36.896439+00:00 app[worker.1]:       arrayParser: [Object],
2021-04-09T07:12:36.896440+00:00 app[worker.1]:       builtins: [Object]
2021-04-09T07:12:36.896440+00:00 app[worker.1]:     },
2021-04-09T07:12:36.896440+00:00 app[worker.1]:     text: {},
2021-04-09T07:12:36.896441+00:00 app[worker.1]:     binary: {}
2021-04-09T07:12:36.896441+00:00 app[worker.1]:   },
2021-04-09T07:12:36.896441+00:00 app[worker.1]:   RowCtor: null,
2021-04-09T07:12:36.896442+00:00 app[worker.1]:   rowAsArray: false
2021-04-09T07:12:36.896442+00:00 app[worker.1]: } Result {
2021-04-09T07:12:36.896442+00:00 app[worker.1]:   command: 'SELECT',
2021-04-09T07:12:36.896443+00:00 app[worker.1]:   rowCount: 1,
2021-04-09T07:12:36.896443+00:00 app[worker.1]:   oid: null,
2021-04-09T07:12:36.896443+00:00 app[worker.1]:   rows: [ { timer: '2' } ],
2021-04-09T07:12:36.896444+00:00 app[worker.1]:   fields: [
2021-04-09T07:12:36.896444+00:00 app[worker.1]:     Field {
2021-04-09T07:12:36.896444+00:00 app[worker.1]:       name: 'timer',
2021-04-09T07:12:36.896445+00:00 app[worker.1]:       tableID: 16732955,
2021-04-09T07:12:36.896445+00:00 app[worker.1]:       columnID: 6,
2021-04-09T07:12:36.896445+00:00 app[worker.1]:       dataTypeID: 25,
2021-04-09T07:12:36.896446+00:00 app[worker.1]:       dataTypeSize: -1,
2021-04-09T07:12:36.896447+00:00 app[worker.1]:       dataTypeModifier: -1,
2021-04-09T07:12:36.896447+00:00 app[worker.1]:       format: 'text'
2021-04-09T07:12:36.896448+00:00 app[worker.1]:     }
2021-04-09T07:12:36.896448+00:00 app[worker.1]:   ],
2021-04-09T07:12:36.896448+00:00 app[worker.1]:   _parsers: [ [Function: noParse] ],
2021-04-09T07:12:36.896449+00:00 app[worker.1]:   _types: TypeOverrides {
2021-04-09T07:12:36.896449+00:00 app[worker.1]:     _types: {
2021-04-09T07:12:36.896449+00:00 app[worker.1]:       getTypeParser: [Function: getTypeParser],
2021-04-09T07:12:36.896450+00:00 app[worker.1]:       setTypeParser: [Function: setTypeParser],
2021-04-09T07:12:36.896450+00:00 app[worker.1]:       arrayParser: [Object],
2021-04-09T07:12:36.896451+00:00 app[worker.1]:       builtins: [Object]
2021-04-09T07:12:36.896451+00:00 app[worker.1]:     },
2021-04-09T07:12:36.896451+00:00 app[worker.1]:     text: {},
2021-04-09T07:12:36.896452+00:00 app[worker.1]:     binary: {}
2021-04-09T07:12:36.896452+00:00 app[worker.1]:   },
2021-04-09T07:12:36.896452+00:00 app[worker.1]:   RowCtor: null,
2021-04-09T07:12:36.896453+00:00 app[worker.1]:   rowAsArray: false
2021-04-09T07:12:36.896453+00:00 app[worker.1]: } Result {
2021-04-09T07:12:36.896453+00:00 app[worker.1]:   command: 'SELECT',
2021-04-09T07:12:36.896454+00:00 app[worker.1]:   rowCount: 1,
2021-04-09T07:12:36.896454+00:00 app[worker.1]:   oid: null,
2021-04-09T07:12:36.896454+00:00 app[worker.1]:   rows: [ { savedname: 'iTxKniGhT' } ],
2021-04-09T07:12:36.896455+00:00 app[worker.1]:   fields: [
2021-04-09T07:12:36.896455+00:00 app[worker.1]:     Field {
2021-04-09T07:12:36.896455+00:00 app[worker.1]:       name: 'savedname',
2021-04-09T07:12:36.896456+00:00 app[worker.1]:       tableID: 16732955,
2021-04-09T07:12:36.896456+00:00 app[worker.1]:       columnID: 7,
2021-04-09T07:12:36.896457+00:00 app[worker.1]:       dataTypeID: 1043,
2021-04-09T07:12:36.896457+00:00 app[worker.1]:       dataTypeSize: -1,
2021-04-09T07:12:36.896457+00:00 app[worker.1]:       dataTypeModifier: 24,
2021-04-09T07:12:36.896458+00:00 app[worker.1]:       format: 'text'
2021-04-09T07:12:36.896458+00:00 app[worker.1]:     }
2021-04-09T07:12:36.896458+00:00 app[worker.1]:   ],
2021-04-09T07:12:36.896459+00:00 app[worker.1]:   _parsers: [ [Function: noParse] ],
2021-04-09T07:12:36.896459+00:00 app[worker.1]:   _types: TypeOverrides {
2021-04-09T07:12:36.896459+00:00 app[worker.1]:     _types: {
2021-04-09T07:12:36.896460+00:00 app[worker.1]:       getTypeParser: [Function: getTypeParser],
2021-04-09T07:12:36.896460+00:00 app[worker.1]:       setTypeParser: [Function: setTypeParser],
2021-04-09T07:12:36.896460+00:00 app[worker.1]:       arrayParser: [Object],
2021-04-09T07:12:36.896461+00:00 app[worker.1]:       builtins: [Object]
2021-04-09T07:12:36.896461+00:00 app[worker.1]:     },
2021-04-09T07:12:36.896461+00:00 app[worker.1]:     text: {},
2021-04-09T07:12:36.896462+00:00 app[worker.1]:     binary: {}
2021-04-09T07:12:36.896462+00:00 app[worker.1]:   },
2021-04-09T07:12:36.896462+00:00 app[worker.1]:   RowCtor: null,
2021-04-09T07:12:36.896463+00:00 app[worker.1]:   rowAsArray: false
2021-04-09T07:12:36.896463+00:00 app[worker.1]: } Result {
2021-04-09T07:12:36.896464+00:00 app[worker.1]:   command: 'SELECT',
2021-04-09T07:12:36.896464+00:00 app[worker.1]:   rowCount: 1,
2021-04-09T07:12:36.896464+00:00 app[worker.1]:   oid: null,
2021-04-09T07:12:36.896465+00:00 app[worker.1]:   rows: [
2021-04-09T07:12:36.896465+00:00 app[worker.1]:     {
2021-04-09T07:12:36.896466+00:00 app[worker.1]:       savedavatar: 'https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/410095697233313793/4015931f11053def4ef540d0731690cc.webp'
2021-04-09T07:12:36.896467+00:00 app[worker.1]:     }
2021-04-09T07:12:36.896467+00:00 app[worker.1]:   ],
2021-04-09T07:12:36.896467+00:00 app[worker.1]:   fields: [
2021-04-09T07:12:36.896468+00:00 app[worker.1]:     Field {
2021-04-09T07:12:36.896468+00:00 app[worker.1]:       name: 'savedavatar',
2021-04-09T07:12:36.896468+00:00 app[worker.1]:       tableID: 16732955,
2021-04-09T07:12:36.896469+00:00 app[worker.1]:       columnID: 8,
2021-04-09T07:12:36.896469+00:00 app[worker.1]:       dataTypeID: 1043,
2021-04-09T07:12:36.896469+00:00 app[worker.1]:       dataTypeSize: -1,
2021-04-09T07:12:36.896470+00:00 app[worker.1]:       dataTypeModifier: 504,
2021-04-09T07:12:36.896471+00:00 app[worker.1]:       format: 'text'
2021-04-09T07:12:36.896471+00:00 app[worker.1]:     }
2021-04-09T07:12:36.896471+00:00 app[worker.1]:   ],
2021-04-09T07:12:36.896471+00:00 app[worker.1]:   _parsers: [ [Function: noParse] ],
2021-04-09T07:12:36.896472+00:00 app[worker.1]:   _types: TypeOverrides {
2021-04-09T07:12:36.896472+00:00 app[worker.1]:     _types: {
2021-04-09T07:12:36.896482+00:00 app[worker.1]:       getTypeParser: [Function: getTypeParser],
2021-04-09T07:12:36.896482+00:00 app[worker.1]:       setTypeParser: [Function: setTypeParser],
2021-04-09T07:12:36.896483+00:00 app[worker.1]:       arrayParser: [Object],
2021-04-09T07:12:36.896483+00:00 app[worker.1]:       builtins: [Object]
2021-04-09T07:12:36.896483+00:00 app[worker.1]:     },
2021-04-09T07:12:36.896484+00:00 app[worker.1]:     text: {},
2021-04-09T07:12:36.896484+00:00 app[worker.1]:     binary: {}
2021-04-09T07:12:36.896484+00:00 app[worker.1]:   },
2021-04-09T07:12:36.896485+00:00 app[worker.1]:   RowCtor: null,
2021-04-09T07:12:36.896485+00:00 app[worker.1]:   rowAsArray: false
2021-04-09T07:12:36.896486+00:00 app[worker.1]: }
```

This is the full code repository - https://github.com/muhitrhn/Beta-Commands

Here are the code lines as variables that are responsible for the fetching process.

```js
const tname = await pool.query(`SELECT name FROM Twitch_DB WHERE guildid = ${message.guild.id}`);
const botSay = await pool.query(`SELECT botSay FROM Twitch_DB WHERE guildid = ${message.guild.id}`);
const tchannelid = await pool.query(`SELECT channelID FROM Twitch_DB WHERE guildid = ${message.guild.id}`);
const tchannel = await pool.query(`SELECT channel FROM Twitch_DB WHERE guildid = ${message.guild.id}`);
const ttimer = await pool.query(`SELECT timer FROM Twitch_DB WHERE guildid = ${message.guild.id}`);
const savedName = await pool.query(`SELECT savedName FROM Twitch_DB WHERE guildid = ${message.guild.id}`);
const savedAvatar = await pool.query(`SELECT savedAvatar FROM Twitch_DB WHERE guildid = ${message.guild.id}`);
```

And this is the code block from which I’m trying to call the variables:

```js
const enabledEmbed = new MessageEmbed()
    .setAuthor(message.member.guild.name + " Announcer Settings", `https://static.twitchcdn.net/assets/favicon-32-d6025c14e900565d6177.png`, "https://twitch.tv/" + user.data[0].display_name)
    .setTitle(`:white_check_mark: Twitch Announcer Enabled!`)
    .setColor("#6441A4")
    .setThumbnail(user.data[0].profile_image_url)
    .addField("Pre-Notification Message", `${botSay}`)
    .addField(`Streamer`, `${tname}`, true)
    .addField(`Channel`, `${tchannel}`, true)
    .addField(`Checking Interval`, `***${ttimer}*** minute(s)`, true)
    .addField("View Counter:", user.data[0].view_count, true);
if (user.data[0].broadcaster_type == "") enabledEmbed.addField("Rank:", "BASE!", true);
else {
    enabledEmbed.addField("Rank:", user.data[0].broadcaster_type.toUpperCase() + "!", true).setFooter(savedName, savedAvatar);
}
```

Comment: The retrieved database rows are in the rows property of the response object you logged. This is covered [literally on the first page of the library documentation](https://node-postgres.com/).

Comment: @JaredSmith So, if i change the code like this ```.addField("Pre-Notification Message", '${botSay.rows[0].botSay}')```, it will work?

Comment: @JaredSmith thank you for the hint. Dumb me 